# How to remember values of input fields after page refresh?

Tags: php

I am trying to make a simple word game.
The idea is user clicks a button and server generates a letter and stores it in an array, and that process repeats ten times (temporary workaround i used below is that i generate all 11 letters at once).
Now from the chosen letters user comes up with the longest word he/she can and
user then submits the word, and computer checks whether the word is in the dictionary, if it is, it says 'Success' if it isn't, it says 'xzy word doesn't appear in our dictionary.'
I am not looking for for all the checks, and security checks, just that 
a) computer stores the letter in an array as user clicks the button
b) computer does the check if user subbmited word is in predifined dictionary (which is in separate .txt file).

Problem(s) i am having at the moment is that every time i click the button all my arrays get overwritten
either with new letter, or are just empty.
I suspect that the act of submiting is reseting everything, but i can't seem to make the program remember
what letters were chosen and doesn't check if word exists in my dictionary.
How one would go about storing stuff permanently?
the code is below.

```
<?php 

//the array to chose letters from (possible letters)
$PosLetters = [
    'a','b','v','g','d',
    'đ','e','ž','z','i',
    'j','k','l','lj','m',
    'n','nj','o','p','r',
    's','t','ć','u','f',
    'h','c','č','dž','š'
];

//generate 11 letters user can chose from
if (isset($_POST['choose'])) {
    for ($i=0; $i < 11; $i++) { 
        $Rndnumber = mt_rand(0,29);
        $Convert = $PosLetters[$Rndnumber];
        $Letters[] = $Convert;
    }

}

//function that does the check wether user submited word is in my  dictionary
function loadFromfile(){


        if (isset($_POST['submitword'])) {

            //load all the words from file 
            $vocab = file('http://localhost/igra_slaganje_reci_php/recnik.txt');

            //check if user submited word is in the dictionary
            if (!empty($_POST['yourword'])) {
                $jki = in_array($_POST['yourword'], $vocab);
                if ($jki == true) {
                    echo 'Success';
                }else{
                    echo $_POST['yourword'] . ' doesn't appear in our dictionary.';
                }
            }
        }
    }


 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        span {
            min-width: 50px; 
            padding: 15px;
            margin-right: 15px; 
            border: 3px solid red; 
            font-size: 25px;
        }
    </style>
 </head>
     <body>
         <form method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="choose" value="odaberi slovo">
         </form>
         <div class="letters">
            <?php 
                //put chosen letters each into it's own span
                foreach ($Letters as $key => $value) {
                    echo '<span>' . $value . '</span>';
                }
            ?>
         </div>
         <div class="subbmitedword">
            <form method="post">
                <input type="text" name="yourword">
                <input type="submit" name="submitword" value="submit word">
            </form>
            <?php
                loadFromfile();
            ?>
         </div>
     </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store $PosLetters in a $_SESSION.
Then each time the page refreshes, you first read out the array from the session before continuing.
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php